# erl_tidy cannot determine module name for escript

Tags: erlang, shebang

I want use erl_tidy to format erlang code, including escript files. 
But this comes out when I format one escript file ([source](https://github.com/schemacs/schemacs/blob/master/erlang/erl_pprint)) after adding `-module(erl_pprint)`. :

```
1> erl_tidy:file("erl_pprint").
erl_pprint: error: cannot determine module name.
** exception exit: error
```

But When I remove the she-bang line `#!/usr/bin/env escript`, formatting goes well. 
So how can I formatteing the code while keep the she-bang line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't treat an escript file as a normal module and give it to erl_tidy. Perhaps you can drop the comment lines using "tail -n+2 erl_pprint > /tmp/erl_pprint.erl", run erl_tidy on the temp file, and then use "cat escript-header.txt /tmp/erl_pprint.erl > erl_pprint.new", if you create a file called escript-header.txt containing the leading shebang line (or lines).

Comment: OK, I found no other way to do this but removing the she-bang line.